# ler os elementos de uma matriz dada por input

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz, input

Tenho um código que representa um tabuleiro de damas (matriz 8x8):

```
print(f'ATENÇÃO: ')
print(f'Insira 0 nas posições vazias do tabuleiro;')
print(f'Insira 1 nas posições das peças pretas e 11 para as damas pretas;')
print(f'Insira 2 nas posições de peças vermelhas e 22 para damas vermelhas.')
print(" ")

matriz=[]
x1=x2=x3=x4=0


def gerarmatriz(l, c, matriz):
    for i in range (l):
        linha = []
        for j in range (c):
            y = input("peça da posição {} {}: ".format(chr(65+i),j+1))
            linha.append(int(y))
        matriz.append(linha)

gerarmatriz(8, 8, matriz)

print ('---' *20)

print(matriz)
```

e eu queria saber um jeito de ler a quantidade de vezes que os números 1, 11, 2 e 22 são inseridos pelo 'usuário' pois eles representam as peças do jogo de damas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amigo acredito que seja essa sua resposta, mas pode dar uma melhorada nas condições colocando em uma função!

```
print('ATENÇÃO: ')
print('Insira 0 nas posições vazias do tabuleiro;')
print('Insira 1 nas posições das peças pretas e 11 para as damas pretas;')
print('Insira 2 nas posições de peças vermelhas e 22 para damas vermelhas.')
print(" ")

matriz=[]
x1=x2=x3=x4=0


def gerarmatriz(l, c, matriz):
  global um, onze, dois, vintedois
  for i in range (l):
    linha = []
    for j in range (c):
        y = input(f"peça da posição {chr(65+i)} {j+1}: ")
        if int(y) == 1:
            um += 1
        if int(y) == 11:
            onze += 1
        if int(y) == 2:
            dois += 1
        if int(y) == 22:
            vintedois += 1
        linha.append(int(y))
    matriz.append(linha)


um = onze = dois = vintedois = 0
gerarmatriz(8, 8, matriz)

print ('---' *20)

print(matriz)
print(f"Você digitou '1' {um} vezes, '11' {onze} vezes, '2' {dois} vezes e '22' {vintedois} vezes")
```

Comment: a e eu tb dei uma melhorada no input

Comment: O problema da sua abordagem seria para a necessidade de que se tivesse que fazer com varias matrizes para serem "processadas" em uma etapa seguinte. Fora o fato de que utilização de variáveis globais em si, é uma péssima ideia.

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/list-count)

Vc quer somente ler? O codigo abaixo cria uma lista de dicionarios e guarda o numero de 1, 11, 2 e 22 nas listas em cada posicao da matriz:

```
dicts = []
for n_lst in range(len(matriz)):
    lst = []
    for n in [1, 11, 2, 22]:
       key = 'matriz['+str(n_lst)+']'
       lst.append((n , matriz[n_lst].count(n)))
    dicts.append({key: lst})
```

Com isso vc tera uma lista com o numero de dicionarios equivalente ao tamano da "matriz" original, no caso 8, cada um apresentando com tuplas, os numeros de 1, 11, 2 e 22 de cada lista da matriz, a saida será algo parecido com isso?

```
[{'matriz[0]': [(1, 0), (11, 2), (2, 1), (22, 1)]},
 {'matriz[1]': [(1, 0), (11, 2), (2, 1), (22, 0)]},
 {'matriz[2]': [(1, 0), (11, 2), (2, 0), (22, 2)]},
 {'matriz[3]': [(1, 0), (11, 2), (2, 0), (22, 1)]},

 ...]
```

Indicando que em `matriz[0]` havia 0 1's, 2 11's, 1 2's e 1 22's, e assim sucessivamente.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/list-count)